# How to retrieve result set from a table where certain values in a column need to be excluded

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I wanted to retrieve only a certain records, but I've no clue how to work that out. Any help is very much appreciated.

I have simplified the table below:

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicles (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Brand NVARCHAR (50), Type NVARCHAR (50))

INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Truck')
INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Minivan')
INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Cars')
INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Crossovers')
INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Toyota', 'Hybrids')

INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Honda', 'Truck')
INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Honda', 'Minivan')
INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Honda', 'Cars')
INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Honda', 'Crossovers')
INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Honda', 'Hybrids')

INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Nissan', 'Truck')
INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Nissan', 'Minivan')
INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Nissan', 'Cars')
INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Nissan', 'Crossovers')
INSERT INTO Vehicles (Brand, Type) VALUES ('Nissan', 'Hybrids')
```

I wanted to retrieve vehicle with the brand Toyota and Honda, yet i wanted to exclude the 'Crossovers' type for Toyota only. How should i query to get result set for all Toyota and Honda types, but not Toyota - Crossovers

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the expected result.

Comment: There is a typo in Table name mentioned in Create Table and Insert statement.

Comment: corrected the typo, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
  from Vehicles
  where Brand in ('Toyota', 'Honda')
   and not (Brand = 'Toyota' and Type = 'Crossovers')
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM Vehicles WHERE  Brand IN ('TOYOTA', 'HONDA') And not (Brand='TOYOTA' and [Type] IN ('Crossovers'))`

**`ID   Brand   Type
1   Toyota  Truck
2   Toyota  Minivan
3   Toyota  Cars
5   Toyota  Hybrids
6   Honda   Truck
7   Honda   Minivan
8   Honda   Cars
9   Honda   Crossovers
10  Honda   Hybrids`**

Comment: The **Toyota-crossovers** only to be excluded. But your query excluded the Honda-crossovers too.

Comment: @SonalPM you are deeply influenced by the below answer and you have modified IN Condition ...

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do

```
;WITH CTE AS (
select * from 
Vehicles vv where vv.Brand IN ('Toyota','Honda') )

select * from CTE C 
where TYPE NOT IN 
(select type from Vehicles where  type = 'Crossovers') 
OR 
BRAND NOT IN (select brand from Vehicles where brand = 'Toyota')
```